# Is it possible to get the name of a range that the active cell is in?

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario: Range is named "Dog" and the named range Dog refers to A1:D4. The active cell is in cell B3, which is within the named range.

Is it possible to get the name of the named range that the active cell is in? ie return the name "Dog"?

Comment: Do you want any Named Range or all the Named Ranges that include the active cell ??

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like the following, which tests the `Intersection` of the `ActiveCell` and each named range.

The `On Error Resume Next`...`On Error GoTo 0` is necessary since `Intersect` will fail when the `ActiveCell` and the named range are on different sheets, or if `n` is not a named range but if it refers to a constant or formula, for example.

```
Sub test()
    Dim n As Name
    For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Intersect(ActiveCell, n.RefersToRange)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print n.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't `n.RefersToRange` be more natural than `Range(n)` ?

Comment: And you'll need to `Set rng = Nothing` before the Intersect each loop (putting the Dim in the loop does not reset the Range variable)

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I know the `Dim` doesn't reset it. I assumed (but didn't check) that `Set rng = Intersect` would have the equivalent effect of `Set rng = Nothing` when the `Intersect` fails. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - Not sure what you mean by consider worksheet scope names - aren't they included in `Workbook.Names`?

Comment: When Intersect throws an error (which it will if ActiveCell and n are on different sheets) rng is not changed.  Therefore if it got set previously you'll get a repeat of the last report.  I think (tbc) wb and ws name collections are seperate

Comment: You're right that `rng` is not changed, updated, thanks. From the [`Names`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.names) docs: "including all worksheet-specific names." EDIT: tested and is working with a worksheet-scoped name. Thanks for the catch on `Set rng = Nothing`.

Comment: Yep, confirmed scope thing too.  One last minor quibble, since you're testing `ActiveCell`, probably should also test `ActiveWorkbook`, because `ThisWorkbook` may not be active. (Personally, I'd wrap it in a function, and pass in the range to test, and loop `TheCell.Worksheet.Parent.Names`)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a more robust way...

```
Sub Test()    
    MsgBox NamesUsedBy(ActiveCell)        
End Sub



Function NamesUsedBy(r As Range)

    Dim s$, n

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Intersect(r, Evaluate(Mid(n, 2))).Row Then
            If Err = 0 Then s = s & ", " & n.Name
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next
    NamesUsedBy = Mid(s, 3)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but this should work.

```
Sub test()
    Dim currentrange As Range
    Dim r As Variant

    Set currentrange = ActiveCell 
    For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Names 
        If Not Application.Intersect(currentrange, Range(Right(r, InStr(1, r, "$")))) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print r.Name
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: But this doesn't take the sheet the named range is on into account, right? Seems like it would lead to false positives.

Comment: yeah it would not take the sheet into account.